# Open menu with hover and close when cursor moved out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

On top of page it has a menu that **opens with click on it**:
[menu opens with click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qikQI.png)

I need to change it to open with **hover**, the code is this:

```
 $(document).on('click','.btn-open-mobile',function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width > 1024){
            if($('body').hasClass('home') && !$('.box-vertical-megamenus').is('.hiden_content')){
                if($('#nav-top-menu').hasClass('nav-ontop') || $('#header').hasClass('option6') || $('#header').hasClass('option5') ){

                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        $(this).closest('.box-vertical-megamenus').find('.vertical-menu-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).closest('.title').toggleClass('active');
        if( width < 768 ){
          $('.main-menu .navigation-main-menu').hide();
        }

        return false;
    })
```

when I replace "click" with "hover", it works But problem is menu is open only if cursor is on "three lines icon". 
How to force this menu continue to stay open until cursor moved out of sub menus.
sorry for dirty code, I'm newbie.

Comment: Do you find that it works if you specify 'mouseenter' instead of 'click'?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a proper parent/child structure.

You need to target the entire div and not only the button when using hover.

jQuery Mousenter
https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
Should give you more freedom to play with your menu.

```
$( "nav" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $( "p:first", this ).text( "mouse enter" );
    $( "p:last", this ).text( ++n );
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( "p:first", this ).text( "mouse leave" );
  });
```